# Trouble shooting date module

Tags: 7, datetime

I am using [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module. I installed it, and as per my requirement for an event node (start date and end date) it worked good. Few days later I was unable to add or change the date. It was not showing the display pop_up calendar. I uninstalled and installed the same module again, and it worked fine; but after a few days the same problem repeated. Is there any way to troubleshoot the problem?

Comment: This is not nearly enough information.  Did you make any changes to your site that may have caused it to stop working?

Comment: The only change is , I dumped drupal site into another server as the earlier one ran into problems.

Comment: So you switched servers and then the problem started?

Comment: Yes. for the first time i removed the date module and installed it again then every thing went good few days later same problem started.